# Textures only showing on some devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am currently writing an Android application that works with OpenGL ES 1.1.
It worked fine on my HTC Desire (Android 2.3.7) where I developed it on. Now I wanted to test it on a Nexus 7 but it only shows a black screen. I found out that all textures are simply rendered black. On parts where no object and no texture is rendered, I get the (almost) black background color.

So my question is why are the textures rendered fine on some devices and not on others?

The textures are all quadratic with a size power of 2 (i.e. 512x512, 1024x1024).
These are the settings used when the textures are created:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, getTextureId());   

// Create Nearest Filtered Texture
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        GL10.GL_LINEAR);

// Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
        GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
        GL10.GL_REPEAT);

gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, /*GL10.GL_REPLACE*/ GL10.GL_MODULATE);

// Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image
// from our bitmap
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

What can I try to get the textures rendered on both devices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're getting your bitmaps from drawables, make sure they are all in drawable-nodpi folder.

Otherwise your power of two image might not be power of two after it gets scaled up on different android densities (a 1024x1024 image in the `drawable` folder becomes 1536x1536 on HDPI devices).

Comment: so I need an extra "drawables-nodpi" folder? Until now I only have ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi... Though they were all...

Comment: Ahh I found it: I need a drawable-tvdpi folder with the textures... When I create a folder with this name and put the textures in there it works fine... :) Thank you!

Comment: Anything you put in a folder called `drawable-nodpi` never gets scaled. So a 1024x1024 texture will always be 1024x1024. If you're just dumping the same texture into 5 different directories that's really wasteful @evident.

Comment: well I was planning to create different size versions of the textures and put them in the different folders. So that tvdpi and xhdpi have the large size textures (I created each one as 2048x2048). hdpi, mdpi and ldpi therefore will have the texture files that are smaller...
Or is this not a good way?

Comment: It's probably ok, but I believe there is some way to use the same texture in multiple dpi folders with some kind of alias, but I can't remember (maybe look around on SO). Just know that if you put multiple copies of a 2048x2048 image in your application that's a lot of wasted memory.  @evident